# Prettier not working in VS code

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code

I am not able to configure "Prettier" into my VS Code.

Followed the following steps:

Installed Prettier and selected Prettier as the 'Default Formatter' for both User and Workspace.

Installed node js.

Ran the command `npm install`

Ran the command `npm i prettier -g`

Extracted the prettier path `npm root -g`

Added the path `'\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\prettier'` to the prettier path as is mentioned in the following solution in "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58866847/in-vs-code-im-getting-this-error-failed-to-load-module-attempted-to-load-pr".
Added the permission 'Format on Save' in the VS code.
But now I am receiving this error

> ["ERROR" - 4:16:59 pm] Error loading node module '\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\prettier' ["ERROR" - 4:16:59 pm] Cannot find module '\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\prettier'.

Any assistance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `\AppData` is incorrect. Perhaps they meant `%APPDATA$/npm/node_modules/prettier`. You can also install prettier locally in your project, which I'd probably recommend if you share your project with people. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67193371/2132791) on that same link.

Answer (score 0):

try this "npm install --save-dev --save-exact prettier"